# A Coincidence concerning 163 and the Monster?

Tags: number-theory, group-theory, sequences-and-series

There is a McKay-Thompson series for the Monster group, namely $T_{1A}$, responsible for,

$e^{\pi\sqrt{163}} \approx 640320^3 + 744$

Another one ($T_{2A}$) for,

$e^{\pi/2\sqrt{232}} \approx 396^4 -104$

And a third one ($T_{3A}$) for,

$e^{\pi/3\sqrt{267}} \approx 300^3 + 42$

It turns out, as proven by Conway, Norton, and Atkin, that ***this family of functions span a linear space of dimension 163***.  I found this so intriguing I had to write an article on it. See,

"[The 163 Dimensions of the Moonshine Functions](http://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0022)"

The Monster is the *largest* of the sporadic simple groups, and 163 is the *largest d* such that $Q(\sqrt{-d})$ has unique factorization. Do you think this is just a coincidence?

Comment: The Monster is the largest of the *sporadic* simple groups. There are arbitrarily large simple groups (there are infinitely many primes, for example!)

Comment: Also related is Euler's famous polynomial $x^2+x+41$, which is prime for $0\leq x\leq 39$, factors as $\left(x+\frac{1-\sqrt{-163}}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{1+\sqrt{-163}}{2}\right)$.

Comment: Yes, you plug $\tau = (1+\sqrt{-163})/2$ into the McKay-Thompson series T_1A with constant term 744, and you get -640320^3.  Given the prime-generating polynomial P(n) = 2n^2+29 which is prime for n = {0 to 28} and plug the root of P(n) = 0 into T_2A, and you get 396^4. And so on.

Comment: It is worth reading the Wikipedia page on Heegner Numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number  There are a lot of interesting things there.  (What I said above, and the relation between those prime generating polynomials and Heegner numbers are in the article.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gukov-Vafa [Comm Math Phys 246, pp 181-110](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2044895) has a remark in section 5.4 page 198.

I am following this up. It seems a knowledge (at least for physicists) of Ishibashi states and the Narain momentum lattice may be helpful.

Work by Connes, Consani, Marcolli, Ramachandran relates quantum statistical mechanics and class field theory.